# How to execute multiple DML statements in a variable sequentially using cx_Oracle

Tags: python-3.x, oracle, cx-oracle

I have a variable SCRIPT which has two to three DML statements. I want to run them sequentially after connecting to my Oracle DB. I have tried the below but it is failing with below error

```
    c.execute(SCRIPT)
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

Below is the piece of code tried.

```
SCRIPT="""UPDATE IND_AFRO.DRIVER
   SET Emp_Id = 1000, update_user_id = 'RIBST-4059'
 WHERE Emp_Id IN (SELECT Emp_Id
                    FROM IND_AFRO.DRIVER Ddq
                   WHERE     NOT EXISTS
                                 (SELECT 1
                                    FROM IND_AFRO_AF.EMPLOYEE
                                   WHERE Emp_Id = Ddq.Emp_Id)
                         AND Functional_Area_Cd = 'DC');

UPDATE IND_AFRO.APPOINTMENTS
   SET Emp_Id = 1000, update_user_id = 'RIBST-4059'
 WHERE Emp_Id IN (SELECT Emp_Id
                    FROM IND_AFRO.APPOINTMENTS Ddq
                   WHERE NOT EXISTS
                             (SELECT 1
                                FROM IND_AFRO_AF.EMP
                               WHERE Emp_Id = Ddq.Emp_Id));

UPDATE IND_AFRO.ar_application_for_aid a
   SET a.EMP_ID = 1000
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
           (SELECT 1
              FROM IND_AFRO_AF.EMP
             WHERE emp_id = a.emp_id);"""

    conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user=r'SYSTEM', password='ssadmin', dsn=CONNECTION)
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute(SCRIPT)
    c.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `execute()` and `executemany()` functions only work on one SQL or PL/SQL statement.

You can wrap the three statements in a PL/SQL BEGIN/END block like:

```
SQL> begin
  2  insert into test values(1);
  3  update test set a = 2;
  4  end;
  5  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Alternatively you can split up your string into individual statements.  If the statements originate from a file, you can write a wrapper to read file and execute each statement. This is a lot easier if you restrict the SQL syntax (particularly regarding line terminators). For an example, see https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/master/samples/SampleEnv.py#L116
However this means calling `execute()` more times, which isn't as efficient as the first solution.